# I get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:21)"

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The problem I have is at line 21, which is `input[Weeks][Results] = scanner.nextDouble();`.

I dont know what I'm doing wrong. The program just basically ask me for how many weeks i want to input and how many results per week and then store them in a 2d array.

```java
package com.company;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many weeks?: ");
        int Weeks = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How many results per week?: ");
        int Results = scanner.nextInt();

        double[][] input = new double[Weeks][Results];

        for (int i = 0; i < Weeks; i++) {
            System.out.println("Temperature Week " + Weeks + ": ");
            for (int k = 0; k < Results; k++) {
                input[Weeks][Results] = scanner.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that error means you are trying to get the third element of an array that contains maximum two elements.

Comment: Ask yourself this: why are you declaring `i` and `k` and are then not using them?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert the data at the same position you have declared as maximum length.

Your array has a size of `[Weeks][Results]` and you are trying to add a double in `[Weeks][Results]` position into loop.

Change values to `i` and `k` like this:

```java
input[i][k] = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Also your `print` line into loop should be:

```java
System.out.println("Temperature Week " + i + ": ");
```

That's not an error, but the print will output always the number of weeks instead of the actual week you want to insert the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Use `input[i][k] = scanner.nextDouble();` instead of `input[Weeks][Results] = scanner.nextDouble();`